# Machine vision camera image not let me use to Tkinter Lable

Tags: python, machine-learning, tkinter, computer-vision, tkinter-label

here i am using baumer machine vision camera and tkinter framework for making gui application. i captured image from camera and convert using PIL Library but lable throws error for numpy array.
this application work for webcam so i cant understand diffrence of camera image data.

```py
import neoapi
from neoapi.neoapi import NeoException
import numpy as np
import cv2 
from tkinter import *
import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


try:
    
    camera = neoapi.Cam()
    camera.Connect()
    dim = (640,480)
    camera.f.ExposureTime = 4000
    camera.f.Width = 640
    camera.f.Height = 480



except(neoapi.NeoException, Exception)as exc:
    print(exc)

root = Tk()


def main():
    while True:
         img =camera.GetImage().GetNPArray()
         img2 = Tk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(img))
         L1['Image'] = img2
         
        
         



L1 = Label(root,borderwidth=1,text= ' var')
L1.pack()    




B1 = Button(root,text='connnect',command= main).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First you should use `ImageTk.PhotoImage` instead of `tk.PhotoImage`.  Second, don't use while loop in tkinter main thread as it will block the tkinter mainloop from updating and handling pending events.

Comment: I tried both ImageTk and tk. what can i use instead of while loop?

Comment: You can use either `threading` or tkinter `.after()`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use `ImageTk.PhotoImage` instead of tkinter `PhotoImage`.

Second better use `threading` or tkinter `.after()` instead of while loop in the tkinter application as while loop will block tkinter `mainloop()` from updating and handling pending events.

Below is an example of using `.after()` instead of while loop:

```py
def main():
    img = camera.GetImage()
    if not img.IsEmpty():
        img = img.GetNPArray()
        # use ImageTk.PhotoImage instead
        img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(img))
        # use L1['image'] instead of L1['Image']
        L1['image'] = img2
        # save a reference of the image
        L1.image = img2
    # call main() after 25ms later (use other value to suit your case)
    L1.after(25, main)
```

*Note that you should avoid calling `main()` multiple times (i.e. clicking <kbd>connect</kbd> multiple times) as it will create multiple periodic tasks.*